# How to add a large number of source files to an IAR .eww

Tags: build, makefile, iar

We debug our binary using an IAR workspace (.eww) that wasn't used to build the binary - it was done using make from the command line. The make files were generated by a build system (exactly how is lost in the mists of time).

Is there a way to add the sources to the .eww after the make i.e. automatically traverse the source file directory structure and add the same sources that make uses? There are multiple copies of some of the sources in the structure due to some sloppy copy & pasting i.e. same file, 2 copies, possibly identical, different directories.

Comment: Is the question how to mass add to IAR? Or how to find the specific files that make used because there might be slightly modified duplicates lying around?

Answer (score 0):

Project files (.ewp) are simply xml files. Source files are listed as

```
<file><name>path\to\source.c</name></file>
```

in `<project>` node.

You could create a script (Python for example) which searches for files or make gives them as parameters. Script could then filter out duplicates and update IAR project file accordingly.

But if you are using IAR compiler to build and workbench to debug, then maybe ditch make file completely and create project file from ground up, so you could build and debug directly from the IDE?